# R: Rows Fulfilling a Vector of Different Criteria

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, vector

Suppose I have a data frame `event_data` that looks like this:

```
  ID event_one event_two
1  A         1         8
2  B         3         5
3  C         9        13
4  D         9        13
5  E        10        10
6  F        13        15
7  G        13        17
8  H        14        17
9  I        15        19
```

The `event` columns are the amount of time that has elapsed from some initial time 0 until the occurrence of the event. So for object `C`, `event_one` happened at time 9, and `event_two` happened at time 13.

What I want is to take a vector of `times`:

```
> times = 0:20
> times
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

And then go through both columns and find out how many happened at each time. The output should look something like this:

```
time    event_ones      event_twos
0       0               0
1       1               0
2       0               0
3       1               0
4       0               0
5       0               1
6       0               0
7       0               0
8       0               1
9       2               0
10      1               1
11      0               0
12      0               0
13      2               2
14      1               0
15      1               1
16      0               0
17      0               2
18      0               0
19      0               1
20      0               0
```

I realize I could solve this just by looping over every element in `times` and iteratively building up the table, but you're not really supposed to do that in R and I suspect there's a cleaner way of doing it. If possible it should also generalize to arbitrarily-many columns (the example I gave is simplified; my real data has a bunch more of these events I have to find the time-counts for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires the `dplyr` package. First, I create a dummy data frame.

```
# Dummy data frame
df <- data.frame(event_one = sample(1:20, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 event_two = sample(1:20, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

Next, I define a function that counts each event using `table` and repackages the output as a data frame.

```
# Tabulating function
dain_table <- function(foo){
  data.frame(table(foo)) %>% 
    rename(times = foo)
}
```

Finally, I apply the function to each column in my dummy data frame and join it to all possible `times`.

```
# Package it all together
Reduce(function(x, y)left_join(x, y, by = 'times'), lapply(df, dain_table)) %>% 
  mutate(times = as.numeric(times)) %>% 
  right_join(data.frame(times = 1:20))

#    times Freq.x Freq.y
# 1      1     NA     NA
# 2      2     NA     NA
# 3      3     NA     NA
# 4      4      1     NA
# 5      5     NA     NA
# 6      6     NA     NA
# 7      7     NA     NA
# 8      8      1      1
# 9      9      1     NA
# 10    10      1      1
# 11    11     NA     NA
# 12    12      1     NA
# 13    13      1     NA
# 14    14     NA     NA
# 15    15     NA     NA
# 16    16     NA     NA
# 17    17     NA     NA
# 18    18      2      2
# 19    19      2      1
# 20    20     NA     NA
```

Answer (score 2):

No packages required. Convert to a factor and table:

```
data.frame(
    time=0:20,
    lapply(
        dat[c("event_one","event_two")],
        function(x) c(table(factor(x, levels=0:20)))
    )
)
```

Less clearly, you could use `tabulate`:

```
data.frame(time=0:20, lapply(dat[c("event_one","event_two")]+1, tabulate, nbins=21))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df2   <- rbind(data.frame(event="one",time=df$event_one), 
               data.frame(event="two",time=df$event_two))
times <- data.frame(time=1:20)


library(dplyr)    
library(tidyr)

df <- times %>% 
  left_join(df2, by=c("time" = "time")) %>% 
  group_by(time,event) %>% 
  summarize(count=n()) %>% 
  spread(event, count) %>% 
  replace_na(list(one = 0, two = 0))

print(df[,1:3], row.names=F)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 20 x 3
> # Groups:   time [20]
>     time   one   two
>    <int> <dbl> <dbl>
>  1     1    1.    0.
>  2     2    0.    0.
>  3     3    1.    0.
>  4     4    0.    0.
>  5     5    0.    1.
>  6     6    0.    0.
>  7     7    0.    0.
>  8     8    0.    1.
>  9     9    2.    0.
> 10    10    1.    1.
> 11    11    0.    0.
> 12    12    0.    0.
> 13    13    2.    2.
> 14    14    1.    0.
> 15    15    1.    1.
> 16    16    0.    0.
> 17    17    0.    2.
> 18    18    0.    0.
> 19    19    0.    1.
> 20    20    0.    0.
> ```

You'll notice that in the `print()` I indexed columns 1:3. That's just because it also creates a 4th "NA" category column representing the times when there were no events. You can just discard that.